# Finding text between the same two characters within a php string

Tags: php, regex, string

So I know how to extract text from a php string when it is cleanly separated by two different characters (ie. [abc])...

However, I am now facing a problematic situation where I need to extract text that is located between two instances of the same character ('/'). What makes it even trickier is that this can happen multiple times within the same string.

An example should help make this clearer:

```
"This is /a/ silly ex/amp/le of what I /me/an."
```

In this case, I would want to grab `'a', 'amp' and 'me'`.

These examples show the variety of cases I might run into (different lengths and cases where I'm not grabbing a whole word but letters within a word).

What I've tried:

```
('/(\/.+?)+(\/)/i')
```

But this, as expected, captures everything between the first and last slashes. The ideal would be a way to match until the NEXT occurrence of a slash, rather than the last one...

I've been googling this for quite some time, but am only coming up with cases with two different delimiters.

Comment: Just a tip, you don't have to use `/` as a separator. When your search pattern includes a `/`, it can improve readability to use a different character and avoid the escaping: `#/.+?/#`

Comment: @miken32 Ah yes, good point. I've used this before (for shorter regex'es, ironically) but hadn't thought of using it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_match_all` to get multiple matches.

```
$string = 'This is /a/ silly ex/ampl/e of what/ I me/an';
$regex = '/\/.+?\//';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);


Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => /a/
        [1] => /ampl/
        [2] => / I me/
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, Kevin! This did the trick. I'm accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(\/)(.*?)\1
```

What is inside of `(\/)` will be what you're matching between. For example, matching between a set of `*` would look like this:

```
(\*)(.*?)\1
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xZ0fS3/1)